# Invisible DIV over image link not working in IE 8/9/10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an image on my page and I place invisible DIVS overtop the image to allow certain boxes to be clickable. Here is an example of what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/FxNYJ/

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari. It doesn't seem to work in IE 8, 9 and 10. I don't remember having this problem before when I used to use this technique. Does anyone have any ideas?

The HTML:

```
<div class="main-image-wrap">
    <a id="bannerlink_selfie_create" href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="overlay-link" style="width:28%;height:10%;top:71%;left:20%;"></a>
    <a id="bannerlink_selfie_join" data-toggle="modal" href="http://google.ca" target="_blank" class="join-link overlay-link" style="width:13%;height:4%;top:89%;left:32%;"></a>
    <img class="main-image" src`="http://ofbuckleyandbeatles.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/testpattern.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.overlay-link {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: why not just use an [**image map**](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/map-and-area-elements.htm)?

Comment: I dont know what you mean: to me it looks the same in firefox and ie. Can you upload a screenshot or something?